# DatabaseError at /post/113/ value too long for type character varying(10)

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am using postgresql on Heroku for my Django App. When I try making comment for my posts I sometimes get this error (again, sometimes not all the time).

Despite of the error, the comment is still saved, but all the code following the save() does not execute.

This problem only occurs on postgresql though. On my localhost where I am using sqlite, everything works just fine.

I am not sure what is the reason for this.

This is how my model looks like

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(post)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    comment_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

That is how my Comment model looks like.
So is it because I did not add max_length for comment?
Here is the Traceback

```
DatabaseError at /post/114/
value too long for type character varying(10)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://www.mysite.com/post/114/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:    
value too long for type character varying(10)
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in execute, line 52
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/venv/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/bin',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.31-py2.7.egg',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Wed, 5 Dec 2012 20:41:39 -0600
```

Comment: enable logging to see which query, exactly, is causing the error on what table, then work your way from there.

Comment: I've added that as well. It doesnt seem to help much though

Comment: AFAIK there's no point of making the char size anything less than 255; it should consume the same amount of disk space.

Comment: @Mark: Actually, there's little point to `varchar(n)` for any `n` with PostgreSQL, just use `text` unless you need a limit; PostgreSQL treats `text`, `varchar`, and `varchar(n)` the same internally (except for the length check on `varchar(n)`).

Comment: @muistooshort: Ah. Good to know. Some databases will use fewer bytes to store the length if possible though, no?

Comment: @Mark: MySQL has a whole bunch of string types with varying numbers of bytes for the length, I can't say about others. PostgreSQL uses 1 or 4 bytes for the length: ["The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case of `character`. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1. Long strings are compressed by the system automatically..."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html). A byte or two isn't worth the hassle anymore :)

Comment: @Jonathan check the postgres log, it will tell you what the query was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't help you with the Django parts (sorry) so I'll just speak PostgreSQL.

Somewhere in your application you have a `varchar(10)` column and you're trying to put something longer than 10 characters into it, you probably have a missing validation somewhere. SQLite ignores the size in a `varchar(n)` column and treats it as `text` which has no size limit; so you can do things like this with SQLite:

```
sqlite> create table t (s varchar(5));
sqlite> insert into t (s) values ('Where is pancakes house?');
sqlite> select * from t;
s
where is pancakes house?
```

with nary a complaint. Similarly, SQLite lets you do ridiculous things like putting a string into a numeric column.

This is what you need to do:

1. Stop developing on SQLite when you're deploying on top of PostgreSQL. Install PostgreSQL locally and develop on top of that, you should even go so far as to install the same version of PostgreSQL that you'll be using at Heroku. There are all sorts of differences between databases that will cause you headaches, this little field size problem is just your gentle introduction to cross-database issues.
2. Stop using `varchar(n)` with PostgreSQL, just use `text`. There's no point to using size limited string columns in PostgreSQL unless you have a hard requirement that the size must be limited. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html):

   > The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case of character. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1. Long strings are compressed by the system automatically, so the physical requirement on disk might be less. [...] If you desire to store long strings with no specific upper limit, use `text`...
   >
   > > **Tip:** There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While `character(n)` has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact `character(n)` is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations `text` or `character varying` should be used instead.

   So don't bother with traditional `char` and `varchar` in PostgreSQL unless you have to, just use `text`.
3. Start validating your incoming data so ensure that it doesn't violate any size or format constraints you have.

You can switch your columns from `varchar(n)` to `text` immediately and keep working with SQLite while you get PostgreSQL up and running; both databases will be happy with `text` for strings of unlimited length and this simple fix will get you past your immediate problem. Then, as soon as you can, switch your development environment to PostgreSQL so that you can catch problems like this before your code hits production.

Comment: It even happens when I add only a "hi" in comments. and it just happens sometimes. Other times even if a paragraph is written no error would show up

Comment: @Jonathan: You need to get more information about the error then. Do you even have a `varchar(10)` anywhere? Are you perhaps using a string to hold a date that is supposed to be in ISO 8601 format (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Comment: I've added my model in the question too,please have a look at it. and no I dont think I am not using a string to hold date.

Comment: Can you include the SQL schema for the corresponding table? Use `.schema table_name` in SQLite or `\d table_name` in `psql`.

Comment: I finally found the problem. It was actually another model that had a CharField wit max_length=10. And I was trying to manipulate that field in my Code as well. So that was causing all the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that PostgreSQL actually checks the lengths of the data against the size of the field and errors out if too large, whereas SQLite completely ignores the specified field size, and MySQL silently truncates the data destroying it irretrievably. Make the field larger.

Comment: I've added my model as well. Can you please look at it and let me know if it is because I did not add max_length for comment?

Comment: I finally found the problem. It was actually another model that had a CharField wit max_length=10. And I was trying to manipulate that field in my Code as well. So that was causing all the confusion.